# Ionic/Cordova & Android 64-bit requirement

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Google [has announced](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html) that beginning August 1st, 2019, all new apps and app updates must provide a 64-bit version in addition to a 32-bit version.  I have an Ionic 3 (Cordova) app, and I'm not sure what impact this has.  What, specifically, does an Ionic/Cordova app need to do to meet this requirement?

> Starting August 1, 2019:
>
> All new apps and app updates that include native code are required to
>   provide 64-bit versions in addition to 32-bit versions when publishing
>   to Google Play.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think Android is just coming late in the game - iOS/Apple required this since 2016. So I guess for plugins that do not support this yet it should be a call to action, but I guess adding such support is not hard.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-build-architecture solved my problem

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It doesn't really depend on Cordova/Ionic, but in the plugins you use.

If any of the plugins you use, has .so libraries, then they should provide a 64 bit version of that library. 
If none of your plugins use .so libraries, then you are good to go.

If you are not sure if your plugins use .so libraries, Google recommends to check your apk (unzipping it or using APK analyzer). If you have a `lib` folder and it has `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` folders, make sure there is also `arm64-v8a` and `x86_64` folders with the same libraries in each of them.

For more information: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Comment: Thanks for posting.  Sorry for being ignorant on this, but how would I know if the plugins include .so libraries?  Would that be visible by going through the plugins/platform area?  Also, if there is (or is not) an .so library, is there anything a dev needs to do as part of the cordova/ionic build process to create a 32-bit and 64-bit build?

Comment: I don't know the best way, but you can check the plugin.xml. .so files are used for c, c++ and NDK libraries, so it's not something usual on plugins. You can check this one in example https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-hello-c/blob/master/plugin.xml#L39-L42, it includes .so files for different architectures. I don't think you need to do anything special as long as it includes the 64 bit .so.

Comment: I've recently been made aware of a 3rd party plugin that we use which provides 64-bit libraries via a `build-extras.gradle` file, which pulls the libraries in via gradle/maven.  So looking at the plugin.xml file for all plugins with `.so` files may be part of the puzzle, but it doesn't appear to be the complete picture.

Comment: If you open the project in Android Studio, do you see a `jniLibs` folder in the root or in `app/src/main/`? maybe there is a better place to look into.

Comment: Looks like you have the essence of the correct answer.  Looking at https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit as a reference, that explains 2 ways to analyze your APK for these .so libraries.  One way is using Android Studio, the other is by unzipping the APK.  Lastly, this link gives a chart on 32 vs. 64 bit expectations.  jcesarmobile - can you reference this link and some of these "How To" details?  Then I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: How can I identify a 64-bit Android phone before purchase? I know how to determine after purchase. I need a 64-bit Android testing device. I can purchase a phone with a 64-bit ARM CPU but that does not guarantee it is NOT running a 32-bit Android OS, only that it can.

Answer (score 3):

1. go to this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-build-architecture and install "**npm i cordova-plugin-build-architecture**"
2. Add the following lines in your "**config.xml**"

---

`<preference name="xwalk64bit" value="true" />`

---

`<preference name="buildArchitecture" value="arm64" />  <!-- [If you want to fetch the 64 bit arm build] -->`

Screen Shot Attached:
[image]

3. Last Step is you can run **gradlew assembleRelease** command in your **cd platforms/android** folder and see the build outputs apk with these folders "**x86_64**" & "**arm64**"

Comment: @tomriddle_1234, can u tell me wat is the error u getting?

Comment: Crosswalk is super old, avoid using that. you should update to latest cordova-android, and  build with the bundle option, however you may still manually copy some lib files to jniLib folder to make is pass Google 64bit check.