# I am missing the x86_64 folder when compiling with gradle. Why?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, 64-bit

Working in Ionic 1, with gradle. I need to publish an app in android playstore, but it fails as it requires a 64 bit architecture and my apk has only three folders for my .so files, which are armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a and x86. I miss x86_64. How can I produce this folder?

If I do separate compiles, I get my x86_64 apk. But this doesn't work on all phones.

Any hint?

Comment: Google has announced that beginning August 1st, 2019, all new apps and app updates must provide a 64-bit version in addition to a 32-bit version
I think you need use all compatible plugin for 32-bit and 64-bit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54483052/6134063

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html